# wheel encoders values

Tags: ros, encoder

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on P3DX. i want to find wheel encoder values from p2os_driver library. In the p2os library, i m directly getting x, y and theta from buffer. Pls. Suggest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217843/wheel-encoders-values/) by [mrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23940/mrobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-09-18**:
Please be more specific. Mention what all have you tried, what exactly is not working and what is the exact issue you are facing. Then, people will be able to help better.

**Comment by [mrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23940/mrobo/) on 2015-09-21**:
My goal is to find dead-reckoning error in wheel odometry. I found the systematic and non-systematic error. I just need raw wheel encoder values to recalculate the pose as per the errors found as above. Or i need the source code for finding pose in ROSARIA or P2OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wheel encoder values are not published by P2OS, or by ROSARIA. The encoders are used to calculate odometry, however. I invite you to dig through the source code, specifically https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/blob/master/p2os_driver/src/p2os.cc

Edit:
Sorry! I linked the wrong file. It has now been updated above. Look at the very bottom of this one, and you will see some relevant information.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23940/mrobo/) on 2015-09-21**:
what does kinecalc do? why is it showing links in the code? is it for mobile robot only? Pls help

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-09-24**:
kinecalc is what calculates the odometry transformation in relevant coordinate frames.

**Comment by [mrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23940/mrobo/) on 2015-09-25**:
http://robots.mobilerobots.com/Aria/docs/classArRobot.html#a34d0e9a99a59b5e8c52ff791806279d1 is the ARIA library and it has command like "ArRobot::getLeftEncoder(void). But, i am not sure how to implement this command on p3dx. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated